# Ping health check failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

I am trying to execute a simple flask app like below:

```
from flask import Flask           # import flask
app = Flask(__name__)             # create an app instance

@app.route("/")                   # at the end point /
def hello():                      # call method hello
  return "Hello World!"         # which returns "hello world"
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(port=8080, host='0.0.0.0')
```

And when I execute it I get:

> This site can’t be reached
> 172.16.75.193 took too long to respond.
> ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

I have tried different ways to handle this like disabling proxy settings, flushing out DNS through the Command prompt, resetting my network settings, etc. But nothing is helping me. Is there any dependency file I am missing or something like that?

Comment: did you tried to use `127.0.0.1`? Maybe it doesn't use `172.16.75.193`

Comment: No it doesn't work

Comment: do you get it when you stat `Flask` or when you try to connect to this page from other computer on internet? Usually local web server can't be accessed from other computers on internet because Internet Providers block access from external client to local server - for security - to stop hacker to access your computer and use bugs in servers. And usually user can't change it. It may need to use tools like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)